# What is the difference between FakeAsync and quiver.testing.async?

Tags: flutter, dart

The [Dart FakeAsync package](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_async) seems to have the same functionality as [quiver.testing.async inside the Quiver package](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver#quivertestingasync) so as a Flutter and Dart app developer I'm confused as to which one to use?

Is one supposed to be used over the other in particular circumstances? nothing in the documentation for either package gives any guidance on this either. Both packages also seem to be authored and maintained by members of the Google Flutter and Dart teams which makes it even more confusing.

The only thing I can see is that FakeAsync package is last updated in July 2018 while Quiver was in Nov 2019, so is FakeAsync deprecated? if so it's not labelled as such. And also a small number of **core** packages currently depend on FakeAsync, while a very large number of diverse package depend on quiver (though can't know if they depend on quivers `testing.async`).

Comment: [`package:fake_async`'s changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_async#-changelog-tab-) does mention it a bit: `package:fake_async` at a time was a superset of `quiver`'s `FakeAsync`.  However, currently `quiver`'s version has diverged, so `package:fake_async` is no longer fully backwards compatible (for example, I added `FakeAsync.pendingTimersDebugInfo` to `quiver`'s version). =/

Comment: Also, FWIW, Flutter uses `quiver`'s, so for better or for worse, I expect that the `quiver` version has more inertia behind it.

Comment: Brilliant thanks @jamesdlin ! I'd happily mark your comment as accepted if you make it a answer.

Comment: FYI, Flutter now uses `package:fake_async`, so reverse everything I said before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried (with limited success) to dig into the muddled history.

[`FakeAsync` was a third-party contribution to `quiver`](https://github.com/google/quiver-dart/pull/98), and a few months later, the author [forked `package:fake_async` from `quiver`'s version](https://github.com/seaneagan/fake_async/commit/94a4187129315b08a90070d1d2203906e954af73).  I don't know what the rationale was for having two separate implementations, but I could guess that perhaps the author wanted to have more direct control over the code. (In other words, `package:fake_async` initially was not authored nor owned by Google.)

I asked around, and my understanding is that `package:fake_async` stopped being maintained, and Google's Dart team ended up taking ownership of `package:fake_async` so that it could be updated for Dart 2.

From [`package:fake_async`'s changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_async#-changelog-tab-), it does appear that it was meant to be a superset of `quiver`'s version, but the implementations have since diverged so that it's no longer fully backward compatible.

<strike>At this point, I personally would use the `quiver` version: it's better maintained and is what Flutter uses, so I expect that it has much more inertia behind it.</strike>

I've also filed https://github.com/dart-lang/fake_async/issues/16 requesting that guidance be added to the documentation.

### Update

Flutter moved in the other direction and switched to using `package:fake_async` instead, so I now recommend using `package:fake_async` too. `package:fake_async` has been updated to be a proper superset of of the `quiver` version.  Also see https://github.com/google/quiver-dart/issues/590.